# Plotting the inverse function of a complicated function

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, inverse

So I have a function

```
F[x_] = Assuming[{Element[x, Reals], -1 < x < 1}, 
           Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x^2 - 1)^2 + alpha*x], x]]
```

I'm now interested in the inverse function :

```
G[x_]=InverseFunction[F][x]
```

But I get no answer from Mathematica...

What I'd like to do is to plot the inverse function, I don't manage to do it... And to play with the values of $\alpha$ please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally, I'd say start with a visualization (and if all you're interested in is plotting then you could stop there, too): `Block[{alpha = 1/2}, ContourPlot[x == F[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 1}]]` -- but the results are not encouraging.

Comment: For some values of alpha `F[x]` is a complex number, so probably plotting `Re` makes sense. To play with alpha use Manipulate: `Manipulate[ContourPlot[
 Evaluate[x == Re@(F[y] /. alpha -> a)], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1,1}], {a, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: One of the problems is that `Integrate` does not give a discontinuous antiderivative that cannot be used to evaluate the definite integral. Is that what you want?

Comment: "...plot the inverse function, I don't manage to do it... And to play with the values of $\alpha$ please." - are you perhaps expecting an elliptic function? It might be profitable for you to first convert your elliptic integral to Weierstrass form, whose inversion might be more amenable.

Comment: Right I think it's linked to elliptic functions ! I'll try to do what you're saying (I don't know yet what is a Weierstrass form)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The antiderivative returned by `Integrate` has some problems.  It might be better to numerically integrate, but take care to avoid the singularity where the square-root is zero:

```
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {x'[y] ==  Sqrt[(x[y]^2 - 1)^2 + alpha*x[y]], x[0] == x0,
    WhenEvent[Abs[(x[y]^2 - 1)^2 + alpha*x[y]] < 1*^-6, "StopIntegration"],
    WhenEvent[Abs[x[y]] > xmax, "StopIntegration"]
    }, x, {y, -3, 3}, {alpha, x0, xmax}, 
   Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &}];

ListLinePlot[psol[0.5, 0, 5], PlotRange -> All, 
 InterpolationOrder -> 3]
```

[image]

*Update: Relationship to the OP's `Integrate[]` result*

It's clear that the definite integral
$$F(\alpha,x;a)=\int_a^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\xi^2-1\right)^2+\alpha  \xi}} \, d\xi$$
will be real-valued as long as the entire interval $(a,x)$ lies in the region above `Root[1 + alpha #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 1]` or the region below
`Root[1 + alpha #1 - 2 #1^2 + #1^4 &, 2]`.
It should also be clear that over either region, $F$ is monotonic and bounded as a function of $x$. A numerical approximation to the optimal bound may be obtained by setting `xmax` to the numeric equivalent of infinity, `$MaxNumber`, in the call to `psol` above.  The bound will be announced in a `ParametricNDSolveValue::ndsz` error and will depend on the initial condition and `alpha`. It corresponds to a vertical asymptote in the graph of the inverse function.  Similarly the time $y$ to reach the point where the square-root is zero is finite, except for $\alpha = 0$, when the expression under the radical becomes a perfect square.

Since any two antiderivatives differ by a constant, the corresponding graphs differ by a translation.  The graphs of the inverse functions will differ by a horizontal translation.  It's easy to translate the `psol` solution to overlap the one shown in @BobHanlon's answer for `alpha = 0.5`:

```
F[alpha_, x_] =  (* Bob Hanlon's definition *)
  Assuming[{Element[x, Reals], -1 < x < 1}, 
   Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x^2 - 1)^2 + alpha*x], x] // FullSimplify];

p1 = Plot[psol[0.5, 0, 5][x - Re@F[0.5, 0]], {x, -1, 3.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[3], Red}, PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> {"psol"}]

Block[{alpha = 0.5},  (* Bob's plot *)
 p2 = ParametricPlot[
   {{Re@F[alpha, x], x}, {Im@F[alpha, x], x}, {Abs@F[alpha, x], x}},
   {x, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"F[alpha, x]", "x"}), 
   PlotLegends -> {Re, Im, Abs}]
 ]

Show[p1, p2, GridLines -> {None, {0.88}}]
```

[image]

*Extras*

Here's a demo to play with the values of $\alpha$:

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet@ListLinePlot[psol[alpha, 0, 5], 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-1.1, 5.1}}],
 {{alpha, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

To play in the other region, change the initial condition parameter `x0`:

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet@ListLinePlot[psol[alpha, -2, 5], 
   PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2], Red}, InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-5.1, 0.1}}],
 {{alpha, 0.5}, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Inverse functions can be plotted using [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) or [`ParametricPlot3D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

F[alpha_, x_] = 
  Assuming[{Element[x, Reals], -1 < x < 1}, 
   Integrate[1/Sqrt[(x^2 - 1)^2 + alpha*x], x] // FullSimplify];

Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{
    {Re@F[alpha, x], x},
    {Im@F[alpha, x], x},
    {Abs@F[alpha, x], x}},
   {x, -1, 1},
   AspectRatio -> 1,
   PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True,
   FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 12, Bold] & /@ {"F[alpha, x]", "x"}),
   PlotLegends -> {Re, Im, Abs}] //
  Quiet,
 {{alpha, 0.5}, 0.005, 1, 0.005, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]